# .htaccess how to make more than one variable to a simple url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hello i want to make a friendly url from the url which is really complex.

My current url is:

mydomain.net/?t=status&b=iid&ref=7007&ty=comment

When a user go on the url I wanna to make it as:

http://mydomain.net/status/comment

is it possible?

Is not. I would need as: mydomain.net/t/b/ref/comment

Comment: yeah its possible, look at mod rewrite.. then come back if you have problems, we aren't here to write code for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display SEO friendly URLs using mod\_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513311/how-can-i-display-seo-friendly-urls-using-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit [Apache document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Here you will find how to rewrite .htaccess mod rewrite.